# Wordpress index.php doesn't load on local server

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a working wordpress site online, running on an Ubuntu 16.04 VPS.  I've typically just edited the files via FTP, but I'm trying to get more organized.  I'm setting up a development machine with VirtualBox running Ubuntu 16.04 (with Windows as the host OS) so I can experiment.  I'm having trouble getting wordpress to load.

I've copied the website files into the VM.  I have PHP 7.0.12 installed in the VM.  I have the database copied over and it's running fine in the VM.  I start the PHP server with

```
cd /path/to/website/public
php -S 0.0.0.0:8080
```

When I visit `localhost:8080` from Chrome in Windows, I get a Page not found error in chrome.  However, I create a public/info.php file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, and then visit `localhost:8080/info.php`, I get the correct PHP info page.

I also tried configuring Nginx inside the VM like I have it on the real server.  I get the exact same results as with the built in PHP server.

When I visit `localhost:8080/wp-admin`, I get redirected to the admin page of the live server.

Any idea on what I'm missing or how I might go about debugging the issue?

Comment: Change site_url in options table,from your live domain to localhost:8080 @CodeSmith

Answer (score 0):

When move WordPress to another domain, Instead of directly copying Database, we have to use Database migration plugins or manually updating content on DB.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Changing_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs

Then use this updated DB and copied files. That will solve your issue.

Comment: I gave it a shot, but it didn't work.  I tried starting from scratch with a fresh install of Wordpress and I've made some progress with it. I can now view localhost:8080/wp-admin.  However, it doesn't add a trailing slash and this causes problems.  On my live server running under Nginx, visiting .../wp-admin, changes the URL to .../wp-admin/.  I'm not seeing that with the built in php server.  The root of the page still says "page not found" with this bare bones install.

Comment: @CodeSmith I'm not familiar with VM default PHP server. I believe that, you need APACHE, NGNIX etc server to install & run WordPress.